# Why does path-restricted 'git log' omit merge commits with interesting conflict resolutions?

Tags: git, merge, git-log, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

If a file's history includes a merge commit with an "interesting" conflict resolution, `git log` will skip over it.  Why is this, and how can I make that commit be included?

(By "interesting", I mean a resolution that doesn't just take the version from `HEAD` or `MERGE_HEAD` verbatim.)

For example, in [this sample repository](https://github.com/jerith666/merge-log-test),  I've prepared a simple history that illustrates the problem:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph 
* 4a69f452 add -stuff at C and G
*   9fc8e8bf resolve E-alpha + E-beta as E-gamma
|\  
| * 95bc62e9 add -beta suffix on lines E and J
* | 465abd9e add -alpha suffix on lines A and E
|/  
* f43dc68c initial ten-line A..J file
```

The merge commit resolved the conflict by introducing an entirely new version of the `E` line:

```
$ git show 9fc8e8bf -U0 | grep -A100 ^@@
@@@ -5,1 -5,1 +5,1 @@@
- E-alpha
 -E-beta
++E-gamma
```

However, `git log` totally glosses over this.  The commits it lists fail to explain the current state of the `E` line in `test.txt`:

```
$ git log --oneline 4a69f452 test.txt
4a69f452 add -stuff at C and G
95bc62e9 add -beta suffix on lines E and J
465abd9e add -alpha suffix on lines A and E
f43dc68c initial ten-line A..J file
```

Is there an option I can give to `git log` that will make it include the merge commit?

Other commands, like `git blame`, do show that the `E` line was last touched in the `9fc...` merge commit:

```
$ git blame -L5,5 4a69f452 test.txt
9fc8e8bf9 (Matt McHenry 2016-12-28 16:55:10 -0500 5) E-gamma
```

(Note: the above outputs are produced by git version `2.11.0`.)

Comment: Which version of Git are you using?  Using 2.7.4, `git log --oneline 4a69f452 test.txt` shows the `9fc` commit for me.

Comment: Add `--cc` and `git log` will look at a combined-diff and should find the change. I'm not sure why the default options are the way they are. (They seem to vary a bit from one Git version to another, and when I try your example, cloned from your GitHub link, in 2.10.1, I see the `9fc` commit.)

Comment: @torek you're right, `--cc` does make it pick up that commit.  Despite it being listed in the "Diff Formatting" section of the man page, which makes it sound as though it should *not* impact the commits included in the log!

Do you get the merge commit even without `--cc` in `2.10.1`?

Comment: I updated the question to include the version of git I'm using, `2.11.0`.

Comment: I do see that commit, without `--cc`, in 2.10.1. (I had to explicitly `git checkout` something—I think it was `gamma`—first, so that Git could find the file.)  BTW, see https://github.com/git/git/commit/82dee4160cc6d1b0d792c9f07b5803cd42abc610 - it looks as though before 2.6.0 you had to use an explicit `-m`. I'm also not sure why I see it without `--cc` myself, since without one of the various options, Git has that "ignore merges" flag set.

Comment: Ah, `-m` *also* makes the merge commit appear for me.  It's *really* misleading that these options are in the "Diff Formatting" section of the man page ... have I said that yet?  :)

Comment: I cannot recreate this behaviour.   I've tried Git v1.7.6, v2.11.0, and v2.7.4, and they all output the correct list with "git log --oneline 4a69f452 test.txt".  I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks to the "works for me" reports from @K.A.Buhr, @torek, and @G.SylvieDavies, I tried this on another machine known to be running an identical `git` binary, and couldn't reproduce it.  That led me to comparing the `~/.gitconfig` files and finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have the `log.follow` config option set to `true` or, equivalently, if you pass `--follow` to the log command.

The documentation for this option says it "does not work well on non-linear history".  I guess this is what they mean.  :(

```
$ git log --oneline 4a69f452 -- test.txt
4a69f45 add -stuff at C and G
9fc8e8b resolve E-alpha + E-beta as E-gamma
95bc62e add -beta suffix on lines E and J
465abd9 add -alpha suffix on lines A and E
f43dc68 initial ten-line A..J file
```

---

```
$ git log --oneline 4a69f452 --follow -- test.txt
4a69f45 add -stuff at C and G
95bc62e add -beta suffix on lines E and J
465abd9 add -alpha suffix on lines A and E
f43dc68 initial ten-line A..J file
```